# iBatis mapping: map a string field into a List<String>

Tags: java, sybase, ibatis

is it possible to map a string field with a particular format like:

aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd

into a List having elements [aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd] using iBatis?

What I need is to have in my model something like:

```
public class Request{
    private List<String> fieldOne;
    public List<String> getFieldOne(){....}
    public void setFieldOne(){....}
}
```

even if in my table the field is a simple string. Is this possible?

Thanks
Roberto

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it through a [CustomType Handler](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/java/user/com/ibatis/sqlmap/client/extensions/TypeHandlerCallback.html):

For example, in your mapping you  define:

```
<result column="FIELD_ONE" property="fieldOne" 
        jdbcType="VARCHAR" typeHandler="com.xxx.StringSplitTypeHandlerCallBack" />
```

and then you code your `class StringSplitTypeHandlerCallBack implements TypeHandlerCallback` , which would call `String.split()` inside the `getResult()` method.

UPDATE: Of course, if this conversion is only need for one field of one class, it might be more simple  to define a pair of alternative setter/getters `getFieldOneAsString(), setFieldOneAsString()` in your class, and use `property="fieldOneAsString"` in your mapping

Answer (score 6):

Use TypeHandler, Example:

```
<result property="strList" column="rp_str" typeHandler="com.yourproject.repository.orm.StringSplitTypeHandler" />
```

---

```
public class StringSplitTypeHandler implements TypeHandler<List<String>> {

    @Override
    public void setParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, List<String> parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        if (parameter != null) {
            ps.setString(i, parameter.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
        String columnValueStr = rs.getString(columnName);
        if (columnValueStr != null) {
            return Arrays.asList(columnValueStr.replaceAll("[ ]", "").split(","));
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        String columnValueStr = rs.getString(columnIndex);
        if (columnValueStr != null) {
            return Arrays.asList(columnValueStr.replaceAll("[ ]", "").split(","));
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        String columnValueStr = cs.getString(columnIndex);
        if (columnValueStr != null) {
            return Arrays.asList(columnValueStr.replaceAll("[ ]", "").split(","));
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

---

I'm not sure why you want iBatis to do it, but you could just use [String.split()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to do the work, and map the results.

Comment: yep I know how to do that on the java-side, I just wanted to know if it would be possible to do that automatically with ibatis